# error FS0001: The type 'float' does not match the type 'obj'

Tags: f#

When I try to iterate through a 2darray of floats and try to compare an element with a float it won't let me. I get the error: "error FS0001: The type 'float' does not match the type 'obj'"

Have tried casting "elm" in the loop but it does not work.

```
let arr = array2D   [[1.0;  2.0; 3.0]
                     [4.0;  5.0; 6.0]
                     [7.0;  8.0; 9.0]]

for elm in retval do
    if elm = 0.0 then 
        printfn "yes"
```

Comment: What is `retval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that .Net multidimensional arrays don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only the non-generic `IEnumerable`, so your loop variable is typed as `obj`. You have a few options.

**Cast the loop variable**

```
if elm :?> float = 0.0 then
```

**Cast the array elements**

```
for elm in Seq.cast<float> arr do
```

Additionally, I would caution you to avoid doing equality comparisons using `float` or `double`, because that won't always work due to how floating point representations are handled. For example, in the multidimensional array you've presented, as `double` values the 1.0 value is actually 1.0000000000000557. Floating point numbers are for things that have to be just accurate *enough* but not completely precise.